# Is a 3d array contiguous in memory, what about a 2d?

Tags: c++, c, arrays

If I declare a 2d c-style array of

`int data[X][Y]`

I am assuming that the compiler will create this as a single array similar to

`int data[X*Y]` but is this guaranteed?

Let's say for simplicity we are using standard compilers on an x86 architecture. Now what about

`int data[X][Y][Z]`?

Does the compiler create this as a contiguous block of memory and just do some fiddling with the offsets?

I normally use a single vector for a 2d array with offsets row * NumCols + col and have an inline function to calc it for me, but I was interested in a 3d array for this question. I should also ask if anyone has done this with a single vector and what would be the offset logic as well.

Comment: The standards can't quite make up their minds on this. On one hand, they do require the arrays to be contiguous, but on the other hand they make most things you could do that depend on it (such as trying to use `data[0][0][Z+1]`) undefined behavior.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: I'd say the standards *have* made up their mind: arrays must be contiguous *and* `data[0][0][Z+1]` has undefined behavior. (You can treat any object as an array of `unsigned char`, which exposes and depends on the contiguous layout.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, multi-dimensional arrays of any order in C are contiguous.  They're just "arrays of arrays", so to speak.  Plenty more at the [comp.lang.c FAQ, section 6, Arrays and Pointers](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html).

Comment: This is a great link by the way +1 for it. I wish I had this link back in college

Answer (score 6):

The resulting arrays will be contiguous in the virtual memory area assigned to your process. The arrays may not be contiguous in physical memory, but that shouldn't matter to you.

Comment: The distinction between virtual and physical memory is very important here, and a lot of the other answers seem to miss this.

Comment: Why is it important?  You should never have to care about the difference unless you're writing the virtual memory system.  If you don't *have* virtual memory, they *will* be contiguous.

Comment: @ChristianTernus: It may compile, but you will crash with an SO exception when you run your program. "It compiles" doesn't mean "it is correct" or "it will actually work".  Your compiler doesn't know anything about virtual memory, so that "test" is irrelevant.

Comment: @ChristianTernus: The Standard doesn't require that it runs fine.  Your particular implementation chose to optimize out an unused variable, but that is by no means portable.

Comment: @CarlNorum: It is not important in terms of how to use the array, which is why the statement is qualified with "shouldn't matter". It is only important in terms of providing a factually correct answer to the question.

Comment: Thank you for your help. There's no need to be rude.

Comment: Do any of you know how to create a 3d array with a vector and what the offset logic would be? I tend to stick with vectors instead of c-style arrays because of the boundary conditions and the the lack of being able to dynamically grow the memory when needed.

Comment: Use `std::vector<std::array<...>>` . `std::vector<std::vector<...>>` will not be contiguous.

Comment: is there a way to use a single vector something like std::vector<int> ( X*Y*Z )? Similar to std::vector<int>(X*Y) using offset logic row * Y + col for a 2d array?

Comment: Yes, but it is a low level solution to your problem. Are none of `X`, `Y`, and `Z` constants?

Comment: X and Y could be considered constants in this case. It is Z that is the variable one.

Comment: Then you should use `std::vector<std::array<std::array<int, X>, Y>>`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. upvoting your comments.

Comment: one more question, would that be contiguous since we are using std::array ?

Comment: Yes, `vector` of `array` would by dynamically allocated (because of `vector`) but contiguous.

Comment: @ChristianTernus: The whole point of virtual memory is that you don't have to care that it's virtual. Physical memory allocation isn't even visible unless you're writing kernel code. There might be some performance implications if the virtual-to-physical mapping is fragmented, but there's not much a user-space program can do about that anyway.

Comment: I _am_ aware of the physical/virtual memory distinction; I've [written an OS kernel page allocator before](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2012/overview.html), which is why I brought it up. Who says the asker isn't, or won't be?

Comment: @ChristianTernus: If you want to make the point that the distinction can be important, you should probably explain why.

Answer (score 2):

The elements in the arrays are guaranteed to be contiguous, so the layout is the same in both cases.